# Как заменить строку map на цикл?

Tags: python

Есть код, где содержится `map`.

Но я хочу заменить строку `map` на цикл.

Вот сам код:

```py
import operator  
from pprint import pprint   
a="fjfdsjmvcxklfmds3232dsfdsm"  
hest = dict(map(lambda letter:(letter,len(a)-len(a.replace(letter,''))),a))  

print (pprint(sorted(hest.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hest = dict(map(lambda letter:(letter,len(a)-len(a.replace(letter,''))),a))
```

Ну вот буквально так будет, если расшифровать `map` именно в `for`:

```
hest = dict()
for letter in a:
    hest[letter] = len(a)-len(a.replace(letter,''))
```